# MySQL pattern matching with character exception

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

I'm trying to compare the results of two queries, one acquiring call IDs for calls made to my Asterisk server externally (10 digits) and the other acquiring call IDs connected to FROM the server (11 digits). The outbound calls are prepended a '1' before their number. Currently I'm using a statement like the following:

```
select data2, from_unixtime(time_id) day from queuemetrics.queue_log
where time_id > '1346475600' and (data2, time_id) in
(select dst, unix_timestamp(calldate) from asteriskcdrdb.cdr
where calldate > '2012-09-01' and lastdata like <blocked for privacy>)
order by day;
```

`data2` is the column holding the 10 digit numbers, `dst` holds the 11 digit numbers. Is there a way I can pattern match the 2-11th characters of a column ONLY? To just skip over the first one? Obviously a `LIKE` or `RLIKE` would be useful, but I really need to maintain the nested query for this to work. Any help would be great. Also, pay no attention to my weird use of `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp`. I was experimenting with figuring if I needed my times in the same format for the search to work. Not important.

Comment: On a side note, `calldate` is stored as a date, and `time_id` is stored as a Unix timestamp. I've been playing with trying to convert the two between each other's data types, so this code looks confusing. It wasn't until later I realized I had discrepancy in the length of the caller IDs themselves. Please overlook my strange syntax.

Comment: click "edit" to change the text of your question :-)

Comment: Thanks, forgot I could do that haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [RIGHT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_right) to extract the rightmost characters of a string:

```
RIGHT(your_field_here, 10);
```

If there are some characters you want to ignore at the beginning AND at the end of the string, then you may use [SUBSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substr):

```
SUBSTR(your_field_here, 2, 10);
```

Your query would then be:

```
SELECT data2, FROM_UNIXTIME(time_id) day FROM queuemetrics.queue_log
WHERE time_id > '1346475600' AND (data2, time_id) IN
(SELECT SUBSTR(dst, 2, 10), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(calldate) FROM asteriskcdrdb.cdr
WHERE calldate > '2012-09-01' AND lastdata LIKE <blocked for privacy>)
ORDER BY day;
```

Comment: Perfect! The query is taking a while, so I'm unsure if this is the total fix I need, but it definitely got me on the right path. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Why not trim the leading digit from your dst field?